# Is there a rights managment system for linux in company networks for local root support?

Tags: linux, networking, root

I work at a large research institute (10k users) with various systems (Mostly Windows and Ubuntu Linux). I am not an expert in such network structures but I work at home with Ubuntu myself and like to install software as well. We do have a whitelist for sudo to install generic dep packages. However we do not have full sudo access. Windows users have a full administrator account on windows. My admin told me, that we can not have full sudo access on our local laptops because then I could also switch user to the account of my admin for example and have network wide root access. I am wondering, if there is no solution that would allow me to be local root without network wide root access. My admin told me that this is not possible.

Does anyone know of such a rights management system that would allow local root but not network wide root?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I doubt any system not designed to keep arbitrary network access and arbitrary access to networked devices separate is appropriate for the world of today. Are you talking about `nfs`?

Comment: Honestly I do not know HOW the backend works. I just like to now if there is ANY such solution... I honestly do not believe that my admin is right and I am pretty sure that there must be a solution for such a case (possibly even open source).

Comment: If getting access to root on a laptop means you get root access to the entire network, something is badly screwed up in the way they have implemented their security, but I have no idea what they would be doing, that would mean root on a laptop means root for every system on the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> with full sudo access on our local laptops  I could also switch user to the account of my admin for example and have network wide root access

That can indeed be the case, but that speaks of an old-school and rather legacy network/authentication setup based on trust with a number of weak links such as for example:

- home directories are stored on NFS exports (and access to them is not secured with for instance Kerberos nor is your workstation limited to access only map your home directory, rather it can access all home directories)
- with full unrestricted root access it is then trivial to use `su - admin_login`  and add your own public key to the admin's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- with your own private ssh key you can then login directly as that admin on all servers where the admin's home directory is mounted and which allow ssh public key authentication
- when the admin has set up their account with the `NOPASSWD` keyword in their sudo policies or relies `wheel` (or another group) membership and   no subsequent other authentication/password is  needed to become root or perform other privileged  actions...

---

If the above describes the issues/risks in your network then your Linux/UNIX still relies on a very classic trust model for security.

Any competent administrator should have stopped doing that a long time ago already,   but there may have been legacy concerns and considerations...

When your Linux/UNIX network relies on trust and access to resources is not otherwise secured,  then the security of the devices that are trusted becomes extremely important. In general placing that security in the hands of end-users is ill-advised. In other words, you don't grant full root access to end-users.

Windows Active Directory / domain security does not rely so much on trust (it evolved later than Unix and then had much less legacy and could benefit from improved insights) but uses a much robust security model for network security, based on Kerberos authentication.
In that regard the security of the end-device is less of an issue as those are not implicitly trusted  and granting users local admin rights poses less of a risk.

> Does anyone know of such a rights management system that would allow local root but not network wide root?

After removing the legacy setup almost any system could do that. FreeIPA, sssd, integrate with your Windows AD domain etc. etc.

But that requires that your Linux/UNIX network stops relying (solely) on legacy trust and IP-address/hostname based access controls. Implement for example one of the many proper/stronger authentication systems built around either native Kerberos or integrated with AD.

Stop using "trust" (IP-addresses/hostnames) as the only security control and enable proper authentication on network resources. Start for example with the NFS shares containing home directories and  migrate them to always require "proper" authentication methods such as Kerberos, or switch to CIFS/SMB that also supports client authentication.

Then the security of your network is no longer solely dependant on the security of trusted devices but rather on users keeping their credentials secure.

Once you do that you can consider granting end-users like yourself more control over  their workstations.

Additionally: Administrators should probably also start having more security controls applied to their accounts and for instance not make use of NOPASSWD in their centrally managed sudo policies either.

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu (and UNIX globally), the special root user is the super-user. He can do ANYTHING and you can't disallow some functionnalities and allow other. We you are root, we can do what you want like switching to other user accounts, change OS settings, get network flux, etc...

The good practise is to unallow anyone to log in as root (in ubuntu, the account is disabled by default) and you have to give access to elevated commands by editing the `/etc/sudoers` with the `visudo` command.

In this file you can give root access to some commands to some users, like explained in the *sudoers* entry of the manual (copy available [here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)).

So, the good practise is to disallow everything, and allow parts to parts the commands you authorize. I don't know other solutions and I'm curious to know if someone else answer this problem in an other way.

Comment: You are just repeating the situation the OP already is in. If you are curious, bookmark or follow the question. 'I don't know any solution' is not a helpful answer.

Comment: I reexplained the question with the official UNIX recommandations, detailled why it's not a good way to give full root access and why we can't split root rights. Additionnaly I said "I don't know OTHER solutions", then before loosing time to comment explainations, please read right the answers, it'll save time for everyone :)

Comment: So Windows can do this but Linux not? I would be surprised by that ...